# Getting Selected Value from ListBox on DoubleClick, Web App, Not Windows Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, listbox, double-click

I have an ASP.Net website with C# code Behind. I'm trying to get the selected Value on a double click from an asp.net List Box. All the solutions I see are for Windows Forms, were there is actually a Doubleclick event. No such luck for the System.Web.UI.WebControls version of the ListBox.

Need the doubleclick to trigger a method in the code behind that allows me to read the selected value.

There are a lot of posts out there on this, but they are not applicable to System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox.

Here is a sampling of the code:

.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="XXX-AddressBook.aspx.cs" EnableViewState="true" Inherits="VRV_AddressBook" %>

<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <%-- <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, chrome=1"/>--%>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">

<style>
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
</SCRIPT>

    <title> Address Book</title>
</head>
<form id="frmAddressBook" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:ListBox ID="lstbxddNames" runat="server"  Rows="17" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Proposed Method from .aspx.cs page, with no way of triggering because there is no doubleclick action in the Web Ap version:

```
private void lstbxddNames_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstbxddNames.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lstbxddNames.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lstbxddNames.Items[i].Selected)
            {

                string Test = lstbxddNames.Items[i].Value.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I am loading the ListBox:

```
DataTable dt_UserRS = new DataTable();
```

I then load the contents of the Datatable from a SQL Query (Code not shown)

```
    if (Choice.ToUpper() == "GLOBAL")
    {
        lstbxddNames.DataSource = dt_UserRS;
        lstbxddNames.DataTextField = "Name";
        lstbxddNames.DataValueField = "Email";
        lstbxddNames.DataBind();
    }
```

Here is the solution that i am using. I actually tried this before posting, but I put it in the wrong place in the PageLoad(I put it in the if (!IsPostBack) section in error).

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "lstdbclick")
            {
                lstbxddNames_DoubleClick(lstbxddNames.SelectedValue.ToString());

              //  string TEST = lstbxddNames.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
            lstbxddNames.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(lstbxddNames, "lstdbclick"));

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ViewState["ViewStateId"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //PART OF PAGE REFRESH DETECTION
                Session["SessionId"] = ViewState["ViewStateId"].ToString();
```

Made sure it would hit the method as well:

```
private void lstbxddNames_DoubleClick(string Value)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Value))
    {

        string Test = Value;
    }

}
```

What is happening here?
One thing I don't understand is why were adding the attribute? If I can detect the doubleclick with the event argument, why am I adding the attribute?

Comment: on double click of what? Sounds like a good candidate for `javascript`

Comment: Double click of an item in the listbox. I am terrible at Javascript, hence the C# solution. If you can make the Javascript solution idiot proof for me, I would welcome the help !

Comment: Provide me with the `html` markup of your listbox and I can do that.

Comment: "Need the doubleclick to trigger a method in the code behind..." You don't *need* a dbl-clk to trigger a method. A single click will work.

Comment: Its a multi select List box. If a user is selecting multiple items, the first click will trigger before the rest of the items are selected.

Comment: I've added some of the code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

In your listbox loop you can wire the double click event to each item. e.g.

```
 item.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "functionCall();");
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. The Listbox loop has to be triggered by a doubleclick to start the code. ListBox has no "DoubleClick" action.

Comment: For Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Jobesk- Do you mean when I am populating the ListBox? Are you saying I can add that attribute then ? (Even if there is no native action for DoubleClick?)

Comment: You want to create a double click action on the list box itself or to its items? You can do it both ways, just add the attribute at run time accordingly.

Comment: Its Items. How do I add the attribute at runtime and where in the code do I add it?

Comment: I added some code on how I load the Listbox. Is this where I would wire up a DoubleClick event, and if so, how?

Comment: I found a solution that works, based on Event Argument. I posted the code to the original question. Can someone explain how this works?